# In SqlCommand.Parameter.Add() method, length Parameter is compulsory or not?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@blah", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = blah;
```

In this code length of parameter is compulsory or not?

Also, if we are not using length parameter in this method any performance or SQL injection related issue is occurred ?

Please  suggest me
Thanks

Comment: It may not be *required* - but I would consider it really good practice to always define your length - it's just clearer and more obvious what you're trying to do, and thus easier for you (or someone else) to later understand it ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> in this code length of parameter is compulsory or not?

I don't think it is **compulsory**. But it would be a good practice when you clarify it. [`SqlParameterCollection.Add(String, SqlDbType)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) takes [`SqlDbType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx) as a second parameter and the length of parameter is not required. Just a tip; if your column is `varchar(max)`, then you should use `VarChar` as a db type.

> and if we are not using length parameter in this method any
>   performance or SQL injection related issue is occurred ?

Performance issue looks irrelevant because length is not **must**. And since you use [*parameterized sql*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) in your queries, you should not worry about *SQL Injection* attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Since it passed as parameter, i don't think any issue will arise regards to Injection. Regarding length if you use `varchar(max)`, that will lead to performance issue as it internally keeps that type as text.

**FInally it is not required to use lengh while passing an parameter**

Answer (score 0):

If you omit the length argument it creates the argument with the size of your data

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@blah", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "this is 22 chars long.";
```

it creates a parameter of type `VarChar(22)`. It is possible that sql server uses that parameter information before doing any work to see if data fits to the column (I'd do that).